# Using find with QAssociativeIterable or QSequentialIterable while avoiding copy in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, find

I am looking for a way to use `find` with [QAssiciativeIterable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qassociativeiterable.html#details) (or [QSequentialIterable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsequentialiterable.html#details)) without incurring a copy. Please see the example below:

```
QVariantMap variant = someData();

QAssociativeIterable iterable = variant.value<QAssociativeIterable>();
// Can use C++11 range-for over the values:
for (const QVariant &v : iterable) {
    // Since v is a reference, no copy occurs if I use it here
    qDebug() << v;
}

// Now find a key
auto it = iterable.find("some key"), end=iterable.end();
if (end != it){
    // We have a value, how can I get a REFERENCE to it?
    QVariant &v=it.???????();
    // NOTE: I know that I can do it.value(), but that would be a copy
}
```

*Is this possible?* What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear: `QAssociativeIterable` only implements a `const_iterator`, i.e. if you were hoping to modify the values via the reference: it's not possible.

But if you think of what the const reference in range-for here does, you see that it simply references a copy, and extends the lifetime of that copy for you.

There's no magic in the range-for. It uses the same iterators you have access to, and it does precisely what you imply is a 'copy'. After all, under the covers, the ranged-for simply does:

```
for (auto it = iterable.begin(); it != iterable.end(); it++) {
  const QVariant &v = *it;
  // your code here
}
```

So, technically you get a copy. But copying a `QVariant` is cheap. It's like any other implicitly shared type, except that it also does small-value optimization for you. It's 64 bits on 32-bit platforms, and 96 bits on 64-bit systems. Copying a `QVariant` that contains POD values costs the same as copying two `void*`s. Copying a `QVariant` that contains anything else (say, a `QString`), costs the same as copying two `void*`s, and an atomic reference count increment/decrement (you'll destroy that "copy' after all). You'd have really hard time seeing any benchmark difference between accessing a `QVariant` via a reference vs. accessing it via a copy.